# Passing abstract class parameters by references to signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I want to pass my objects by reference to their base class:
`connect(pCaller, SIGNAL(sig2(const IBase &)), pReceiver, SLOT(slot2(const IBase &)));`
But I'm getting *run-time* error:

> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'IBase'
>   (Make sure 'IBase' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)

Therefore I add:
`qRegisterMetaType<IBase>("IBase");`
And getting a *compile-time* error:

> error C2259: 'IBase': cannot instantiate abstract class

What's the best way to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I think that you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943496/declare-abstract-signal-in-interface-class/17943699

Comment: It seems that it is impossible. From what I understand, Qt requires copy constructor for parameters given by const reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8457129/4149835

Comment: @VladimirBershov after reading the answer from link you provided I added `Qt::DirectConnection` argument to my `connect` call and it seems to work :) But I'm not sure if it's a "hack" or indeed the right way :) Thanks

Comment: Btw, `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` + `qRegisterMetaType<>()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your class `IBase` must be copyable and constructable, if you want to pass it directly (not throught pointer)
2. You need to register `IBase *` with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro in your header (only in global namespace) - `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( IBase * )`. Pointers is a POD type, so they are copyable/constructable.
3. If you want to pass `IBase *` between different threads, you need to register class with `qRegisterMetaType<IBase *>()` call;
4. It is bad practice to pass pointers throught singals, because it is hard to control lifetime of passed objects.
5. Good workaround: you may register your type with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( IBase * )` macro and wrap your variable with `QVariant`: `QVariant wrapper; wrapper.setValue( p ); p = wrapper.value<IBase *>();`.

Comment: 1. I'm going to pass it as a reference (afaik the same as through pointer) 5. Seems fishy as `reinterpret_cast` sledgehammer, thanks tho. I will try to apply your sugesstions a little bit later

Comment: Alexey, you can't decide, how to pass it. It is by Qt design - if you are passing some data type, it must be constructable + copyable.

Comment: thanks, that will do. Quick question, why are you using `qRegisterMetaType<IBase *>()` when in qt docs they write `qRegisterMetaType<IBase *>("IBase")`?

Comment: It is necessary to pass name only for using of Qt reflection. I really don't need it in all my projects :)

Comment: @Dimirty Sazonov , would you please give more information of wrap variable with QVariant , I want to pass objects through signal/slot between two threads which those objects are from a child class.

Comment: @saeed you may ask more exact question and provide an SSCCE.

Comment: @Dmirty Sazonov let me work on my problem,  If I post a question I will add it's link here. I want to send reference of objects with signal/slot to multiple threads each thread would work on data on it's slot and provide result without changing the source  ,  I am searching for a sample to do it safe and correct

Comment: @saeed it is not possible to send references between threads or with queued connection. In this case parameters will be copied directly.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov  could give me a  link to read more about using signal/slot in base classes with multiple consumer threads. Maybe I am confused with signal/slot mechanism

Comment: @saeed 1) http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html 2) http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because the caller and receiver live in different threads. Cross-thread slot invocations need to be able to copy all of the arguments. Since you're passing a base type by reference, there's generally no way to copy it :(

Comment: I added `Qt::DirectConnection` argument to my `connect` call and now it makes no copies. What do you think about that?

Comment: Actual values are of types derived from `IBase`. Sorry I didn't mention it, thought it was obvious :)

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov "I added Qt::DirectConnection argument to my connect call and now it makes no copies. What do you think about that?" Is the slot thread-safe? If it is, it'll of course work. "Actual values are of types derived from IBase" So?  Yes, it is obvious, and my answer takes it into account, of course :) You can make `IBase` copyable using the virtual constructor idiom.